# Find potential duplicate names in database

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have two tables in a SQL Server Database:

```
Table: People
Columns: ID, FirstName, LastName

Table: StandardNames
Columns: Nickname, StandardName
```

Sample Nicknames would be Rick, Rich, Richie when StandardName is Richard.

I would like to find duplicate contacts in my People table but replace any of the nicknames with the standard name. IE: sometimes I have Rich Smith other times it is Richard Smith in the People table. Is this possible? I realize it might be multiple joins to the same table but can't figure out how to start.

Comment: The logic is clear, but can you share the output you actually want to get? What does it mean to you to identify that Rich Smith and Rick Smith are the same person?

Comment: Exactly! Rick Smith and Rick Smith are the same - maybe their IDs and a count?

Answer (score 1):

You could standardize the names by joining, and count the number of occurrences. Extracting the ID is a bit fiddly, but also quite possible. I'd suggest the following - use a `case` expression to find the contact with the standard name, and if you don't have one, just take the id of the first duplicate:

```
SELECT    COALESCE(MIN(CASE FirstName WHEN StandardName THEN id END), MIN(id)),
          StandardName,
          LastName,
          COUNT(*)
FROM      People p
LEFT JOIN StandardNames s ON FirstName = Nickname AND 
GROUP BY  StandardName, LastName
```

Comment: Thank you, I think this is close but it is only showing people that have a firstname in our standardnames table, there could be other dupes for people that aren't in the standard names table ..

Comment: @AAA Good point. Using a left join instead of an inner join should address that, see my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you need to determine how many duplicates you have in your People table...

```
SELECT p.FirstName, COUNT(*)
FROM People AS p
INNER JOIN StandardNames AS sn 
   ON CHARINDEX(sn.Nickname, p.FirstName) > 0 OR
      CHARINDEX(sn.Nickname, p.LastName) > 0
GROUP BY p.FirstName
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

That's just to get an idea of what data you're trying to find in relation to the Nicknames that may possibly exist inside (as a wildcard word search) the Firstname and Lastname columns.

If you are happy with the items found then expand on the query to update the values.
Let's say you wanted to change the Firstname to be the Standardname...

```
UPDATE p2
SET p2.FirstName = p2.Standardname
FROM
(SELECT p.ID, sn.StandardName
FROM People AS p
INNER JOIN StandardNames AS sn 
   ON CHARINDEX(sn.Nickname, p.FirstName) > 0 OR
      CHARINDEX(sn.Nickname, p.LastName) > 0) AS a
INNER JOIN People AS p2 ON p2.ID = a.ID
```

So this will obviously find all the People IDs that have a match based on the query above, and it will update the People table by replacing the FirstName with the StandardName.

However, there are issues with this due to the limitation of your question.

- the StandardNames  table should have its own ID field. All tables should have an ID column as its primary table. That's just my view.
- this is only going to work for data it matches using the [CHARINDEX()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function. What you really need is something to find based on a "sound" or similarity to the nicknames. Check out the [SOUNDEX()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/soundex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function and apply your logic from there.
- And this is assuming your IDs above are unique!

Good luck